# Extracting NDVI time series(1 year) from Sentinel 2_SR for multiple points and creating CSV files for them

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, sentinel-2

I have a shapefile that has 1500 points. I am trying to extract 1-year time-series NDVI values from Sentinel 2_SR for each point and export it to CSV with NDVI values date-wise and existing UID column from the shapefile. This is what my code looks like:

```
// Load the shapefile asset
var shapefile = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-tilok-research/assets/CI_1500');

// Load Sentinel-2 SR image collection
var sentinel = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR');

// Filter by date and region
var filtered = sentinel.filterDate('2022-05-01', '2023-05-31')
                       .filterBounds(shapefile);

// Define a cloud mask function
var cloudMask = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
               .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
};

map.addLayer(shapefile);

// Apply the cloud mask function
var masked = filtered.map(cloudMask);

// Define a NDVI function
var ndvi = function(image) {
  return image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
};

// Apply the NDVI function
var withNDVI = masked.map(ndvi);

// Reduce the collection to a single image or a time series
// For example, you can use mean, median, max, min, etc.
var reduced = withNDVI.mean();

// Export the NDVI values as a CSV file
// Join the NDVI values with the existing attributes of the shapefile
var joined = ee.Join.saveAll('ndvi').apply({
  primary: shapefile,
  secondary: reduced.reduceRegions({
    collection: shapefile,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
    scale: 10 // change this according to your needs
  }),
  condition: ee.Filter.equals({
    leftField: '.geo',
    rightField: '.geo'
  })
});

// Export the joined feature collection to Google Drive
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: joined,
  description: 'ndvi_values', // change this according to your needs
  folder: 'your_folder_name', // change this according to your needs
  // selectors: ['your_attribute_1', 'your_attribute_2', ..., 'ndvi'] // change this according to your needs
});
```

I get an error at the end **Error: Internal error. (Error code: 13)** Please help me out

Comment: Internal error doesn't occur for a particular reason. What you can try `var reduced = withNDVI.mean().clip(shapefile)`.

Comment: Probably, your issue is in your shapefile (not available).  I ran the code (there is a little error in map.addLayer statement) with three arbitrary points and it was produced a result (features have NDVI values) without any internal error.

Comment: @Padmanabha I think I should remove the mean() because I want the multiple date values. so that I can plot the graph with NDVI values in a time period of 1 year.